# Can you search for "reviewer or assignee" in GitHub

Tags: github, github-search

Is there a way to see what PRs are assigned OR review requested for my account? I can do one or the other with `is:open is:pr archived:false assignee:my-account` and `is:open is:pr archived:false review-requested:my-account`. Any way to merge those results so I can see ALL open PRs I'm involved with? Thanks.

Comment: Would also love this for [Project filters](https://docs.github.com/en/issues/planning-and-tracking-with-projects/customizing-views-in-your-project/filtering-projects#filtering-items)

Comment: Opened [community/discussions#41017](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/41017)